# Radio button in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

How to create radio button in the xamarin.ios (native)? We don't want to use form approach.

We tried using creating custom control but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

You can reference this code:

This is ViewController.cs:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        MyRadioButton rBtn = new MyRadioButton (new CGPoint (50, 50), "RadioButton");
        this.Add (rBtn);
    }
```

This is MyRadioButton.cs:

```
public class MyRadioButton : UIView
{
    private CircleView circleView;
    private UILabel lbTitle;

    public bool State {
        get {
            return circleView.State;
        }
        set {
            circleView.State = value;
        }
    }

    public MyRadioButton (CGPoint pt,string title)
    {
        this.Frame = new CGRect (pt, new CGSize (150, 30));
        circleView = new CircleView (new CGRect(0, 0, 30, 30));
        lbTitle = new UILabel (new CGRect (30, 0, 120, 30));
        lbTitle.Text = title;
        lbTitle.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        this.AddSubview (circleView);
        this.AddSubview (lbTitle);
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(1,0,0,0.3f);

        UITapGestureRecognizer tapGR = new UITapGestureRecognizer (() => {
            State = !State;
        });
        this.AddGestureRecognizer (tapGR);
    }
}

class CircleView : UIView
{
    private bool state = false;
    public bool State { 
        get {
            return state;
        }
        set {
            state = value;
            this.SetNeedsDisplay ();
        }
    }

    public CircleView (CGRect frame)
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        this.Frame = frame;
    }

    public override void Draw (CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
    {
        CGContext con = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

        float padding = 5;
        con.AddEllipseInRect (new CGRect (padding, padding, rect.Width - 2 * padding, rect.Height - 2 * padding));
        con.StrokePath ();

        if (state) {
            float insidePadding = 8;
            con.AddEllipseInRect (new CGRect (insidePadding, insidePadding, rect.Width - 2 * insidePadding, rect.Height - 2 * insidePadding));
            con.FillPath ();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks @alanc liu. It took me some while to modify the radio button and add required events to them. but got it at last. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The BEMCheckBox library that works with Xamarin.iOS (see https://github.com/saturdaymp/XPlugins.iOS.BEMCheckBox for nuget package) provides radio button functionality: https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMCheckBox#group--radio-button-functionality

Comment: Thank you. Easy to setup, works like `RadioButtonGroup` and looks awesome.  
The only issue I've encountered [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/saturdaymp/XPlugins.iOS.BEMCheckBox/issues/5)

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, we can make is possible with customization only. We can make one class where we need to manage actions and images on buttons which will look like radio b button only.
Below is the sample that how we can make radio buttons:

public class OoRadioButtonView : OoBaseSelectionView

```
{
    public OoRadioButtonView(bool hasTextField = false) : base(hasTextField)
    {
        _markSize = 11;

        CheckMark = new RoundCornersView()
        {
            roundedCornerRadius = (_checkMarkSize / 2),
            RoundedBottomLeftRadius = true,
            RoundedBottomRightRadius = true,
            RoundedTopLeftRadius = true,
            RoundedTopRightRadius = true,

            BackgroundColor = ColorConverter.FromHex(PclColors.Background.LightLightGray),

            borderWidth = 2,
            borderColor = ColorConverter.FromHex(PclColors.Common.DarkGray),
            BorderRadius = (_checkMarkSize / 2)
        };
        Add(CheckMark);

        Mark = new RoundCornersView()
        {
            roundedCornerRadius = (_markSize / 2),
            RoundedBottomLeftRadius = true,
            RoundedBottomRightRadius = true,
            RoundedTopLeftRadius = true,
            RoundedTopRightRadius = true,

            BackgroundColor = Colors.MAIN_RED,

            Hidden = true
        };
        Add(Mark);

        CreateCheckMarkConstraints();
    }
}
```

Below is the abstract class that I am inheriting in above class

public abstract class OoBaseSelectionView : UIView, INotifyPropertyChanged

```
{
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            if (Mark != null)
                return !Mark.Hidden;

            return false;
        }
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public RoundCornersView CheckMark { get; set; }
    public UIView Mark { get; set; }
    public UILabel OptionLabel { get; set; }
    public UILabel SecondaryLabel { get; set; }

    public UITextField TextField { get; set; }

    public string TextFieldHint
    {
        get
        {
            return TextField.Placeholder;
        }
        set
        {
            TextField.Placeholder = value;

        }
    }

    string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;

            TextField.Text = _text;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
        }
    }

    protected float _checkMarkSize;
    protected float _markSize;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool HasTextFiled { get; private set; }

    protected OoBaseSelectionView(bool hasTextFiled)
    {
        HasTextFiled = hasTextFiled;

        _checkMarkSize = 22;

        CreateViews();
        CreateConstraints();
    }

    void CreateViews()
    {
        OptionLabel = new UILabel()
        {
            TextColor = Colors.TEXT_BLACK_COLOR,
            Font = UIFont.FromName(Fonts.FONT_NOTO_SANS, 14f),
            Lines = 2
        };
        Add(OptionLabel);

        SecondaryLabel = new UILabel()
        {
            TextColor = Colors.TEXT_BLACK_COLOR,
            Font = UIFont.FromName(Fonts.FONT_NOTO_SANS, 14f),
            TextAlignment = SettingsManager.IsLTR ? UITextAlignment.Right : UITextAlignment.Left
        };
        Add(SecondaryLabel);

        if (HasTextFiled)
        {
            TextField = new UITextField();
            TextField.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
            TextField.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            TextField.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
            TextField.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            TextField.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
            TextField.LeftView = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 10, 10));
            TextField.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
            Add(TextField);
        }
    }

    void CreateConstraints()
    {
        this.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        this.AddConstraints(
            OptionLabel.AtTopOf(this, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_SMALL),

            SecondaryLabel.AtTopOf(this, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_SMALL),
            SecondaryLabel.AtTrailingOf(this, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_MEDIUM)
        );

        this.AddConstraints(OptionLabel.ToLeadingOf(SecondaryLabel, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_EXTRASMALL));

        if (HasTextFiled)
        {
            this.AddConstraints(
                TextField.WithSameCenterX(this),
                TextField.Below(OptionLabel, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_SMALL),
                TextField.Width().EqualTo(150),
                TextField.Height().EqualTo(35),
                TextField.AtBottomOf(this)
            );
        }
        else
        {
            this.AddConstraints(
                OptionLabel.AtBottomOf(this, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_SMALL),
                SecondaryLabel.AtBottomOf(this, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_SMALL)
            );
        }
    }

    public void CreateCheckMarkConstraints()
    {
        this.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        this.AddConstraints(
            CheckMark.AtLeadingOf(this, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_MEDIUM),
            CheckMark.WithSameCenterY(OptionLabel),
            CheckMark.Height().EqualTo(_checkMarkSize),
            CheckMark.Width().EqualTo(_checkMarkSize),

            Mark.Height().EqualTo(_markSize),
            Mark.Width().EqualTo(_markSize),
            Mark.WithSameCenterX(CheckMark),
            Mark.WithSameCenterY(CheckMark)
        );

        if (LangUtils.IsArabic)
            this.AddConstraints(OptionLabel.ToLeftOf(CheckMark, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_SMALL));

        else
            this.AddConstraints(OptionLabel.ToRightOf(CheckMark, Dimensions.GLOBAL_MARGIN_SMALL));
    }

    public void UnSelect()
    {
        if (Mark != null)
            Mark.Hidden = true;

        if (HasTextFiled)
        {
            TextField.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
            TextField.Text = null;
        }
    }

    public void Select()
    {
        if (Mark != null)
            Mark.Hidden = false;

        if (HasTextFiled)
        {
            TextField.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            TextField.BecomeFirstResponder();
        }
    }

    public void Toggle()
    {
        if (Mark != null)
            Mark.Hidden = !Mark.Hidden;
    }

    public void SetOptionLabel(string option)
    {
        OptionLabel.Text = option;
    }

    public void SetSecondaryLabel(string secondary)
    {
        SecondaryLabel.Text = secondary;
    }

    public string GetTextFieldString()
    {
        return TextField.Text ?? string.Empty;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin IOS you only have two options when it comes to radio buttons. You can use a pickerview which acts like radio buttons in the sense that it only lets you select one option. However, if you really want the look of radio buttons than you can use WKWebView and build the form in html and then have a piece of code that takes the radio button states from the webview and preforms whatever operations you need completed.