# Radio Button in Xamarin.iOS listen for tap?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need to get a view with two radio buttons working, where only one can be clicked at a time.  Using the answer posted here by user Alanc Liu: [Radio button in xamarin.ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205634/radio-button-in-xamarin-ios) I've got my View Controller looking correct, but I can't figure out how to listen for the tap to set the other radio button to false.

I've tried playing around with adding a gesture recognizer to the ViewDidLoad method, but haven't gotten anything to work yet (I've mostly just used the storyboard previously to add methods to button clicks).

My View Controller:

```
public partial class VerifyViewController : UIViewController
{
    public VerifyViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {            
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        MyRadioButton tBtn = new MyRadioButton(new CGPoint(100, 300), "TEXT PHONE");
        MyRadioButton eBtn = new MyRadioButton(new CGPoint(100, 375), "EMAIL");

        this.Add(tBtn);
        this.Add(eBtn);
    }
}
```

And his Radio Button Classes:

```
public class MyRadioButton : UIView
{
private CircleView circleView;
private UILabel lbTitle;

public bool State {
    get {
        return circleView.State;
    }
    set {
        circleView.State = value;
    }
}

public MyRadioButton (CGPoint pt,string title)
{
    this.Frame = new CGRect (pt, new CGSize (150, 30));
    circleView = new CircleView (new CGRect(0, 0, 30, 30));
    lbTitle = new UILabel (new CGRect (30, 0, 120, 30));
    lbTitle.Text = title;
    lbTitle.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
    this.AddSubview (circleView);
    this.AddSubview (lbTitle);
    this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(1,0,0,0.3f);

    UITapGestureRecognizer tapGR = new UITapGestureRecognizer (() => {
        State = !State;
    });
    this.AddGestureRecognizer (tapGR);
}
}

class CircleView : UIView
{
private bool state = false;
public bool State { 
    get {
        return state;
    }
    set {
        state = value;
        this.SetNeedsDisplay ();
    }
}

public CircleView (CGRect frame)
{
    this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    this.Frame = frame;
}

public override void Draw (CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
{
    CGContext con = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

    float padding = 5;
    con.AddEllipseInRect (new CGRect (padding, padding, rect.Width - 2 * padding, rect.Height - 2 * padding));
    con.StrokePath ();

    if (state) {
        float insidePadding = 8;
        con.AddEllipseInRect (new CGRect (insidePadding, insidePadding, rect.Width - 2 * insidePadding, rect.Height - 2 * insidePadding));
        con.FillPath ();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Expose a public **event** in MyRadioButton  ,call it when we tap the radio button.

   Code in `MyRadioButton`:

   ```
   //define the event inside MyRadioButton
   public delegate void TapHandler(MyRadioButton sender);
   public event TapHandler Tap;

   //call it in MyRadioButton(CGPoint pt, string title)
   UITapGestureRecognizer tapGR = new UITapGestureRecognizer(() => {
       State = !State;
       Tap(this);
   });
   ```
2. Handle the event inside your viewController

   Code in `ViewController`

   ```
   MyRadioButton tBtn = new MyRadioButton(new CGPoint(100, 300), "TEXT PHONE");
   MyRadioButton eBtn = new MyRadioButton(new CGPoint(100, 375), "EMAIL");

   this.Add(tBtn);
   this.Add(eBtn);

   tBtn.Tap += Btn_Tap;
   eBtn.Tap += Btn_Tap;
   // set the default selection
   Btn_Tap(tBtn);

   MyRadioButton PreviousButton;
   private void Btn_Tap(MyRadioButton sender)
   {
       if(PreviousButton != null)
       {
           //set previous to false
           PreviousButton.State = false;
       }
       //set current to true
       sender.State = true;
       //assign current to previous
       PreviousButton = sender;
   }
   ```

Result:

[image]